# What are these chips in this counterfeit SanDisk compact flash card?

Tags: memory, flash

I bought four compact flash cards from eBay that should have been identical to the one I already owned. The units I received were subtly different from the original cosmetically but most importantly they did not have the same performance. They also came in clear plastic clam shell carriers with no retail packaging.

My genuine SanDisk Ultra has a write speed of 30MB/s write and 60MB/s read on average. These cards are rated for 30MB/s read and write at a minimum. The counterfeits are 10MB/s read and 25MB/s write on average. My card reader is very good and can achieve over 120MB/s with a high quality UDMA flash card and has never had issues with any other media.

One of the cards I bought had problems detecting, formatting, and any attempt to write would fail with the card being disconnected from the system. I decided to open it up to see what kind of chips were used on it. To my surprise they are laser etched as SanDisk. The flash memory also has a matching part number online but I wasn't able to find a datasheet.

Unless SanDisk is selling massively underperforming parts to their customers, I'm confident that the cards themselves are counterfeit but I don't know what to make of the chips. Why would there be laser etched SanDisk components inside? Even the PCB says SanDisk on it. Are these high quality counterfeits designed to fool inspectors, a product of ghost shift manufacturing, repurposed chips that are genuine SanDisk but did not meet spec, or something else?

My original and known-genuine card is pictured on the left next to the counterfeit on right. All PCB photos are of the inside of a counterfeit card.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 4GB CF cards were produced for years. If you take one CF from production start and one from the time when they ended up to produce such cards I would expect a significant speed difference as flash chips have been improved multiple times during that time.

Comment: From eBay you have no guarantee that the cards are new or well looked after. They could also easily have put new stickers on old or slower cards.

Comment: Maybe SanDisk had some lower specced models around this time and these are genuine parts but rebranded and sold as the more expensive variant.

Comment: The are genuine, they buy 1gb cards, hack the firmware to show 4gb and change the label, this has been going on for many years.